# How to save a list in EF 6 using transactions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to find the most proper way to save a list of orders and one of payments using EF6. I would like to know if the sample code below is correct, like for example if the foreach loop is in the correct place?

```
using (ContextDB db = new ContextDB())
{
   foreach (Order item in orders)
      {
          using (var dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())    
          {
              try
              {               

                  // some logic here to retrieve related payment, etc...
                   ...

                   db.Orders.Add(item);
                   db.Payments.Add(pmntRcvd) 
                   db.SaveChanges();   

                   dbContextTransaction.Commit();
               }
               catch
               {
                   // Code to log the exception
                   ...                        
                }  
           }   
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are saving the items in separate transactions. This should be obvious: You create one transaction per item.
2. No need to `Rollback`. If you don't `Commit`, a rollback always happens. Just delete all error handling code.
3. You swallow exceptions so that you never find out about problems.
4. I don't see why you are calling `SaveChanges` that often. Why not once at the end?

Comment: 3. I update the question. There is code to log the exception and the item who caused it                                                                                               4. Because I need to make sure that the item is saved once it is processed. What happens if I call SaveChanges() only once at the end and there is a problem ? Or maybe I dont understand EF6 very well yet.

Comment: (3) you should still delete the rollback and add `throw;`. (4) nothing will be saved in case of error. I understand this is your intention. Call it at the end of the transaction, or sooner if you must.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I removed the first db.SaveChanges() and the rollback.It seems to be working as expected, so far. Should I remove the using transaction as well or keep it?

Comment: The answer is more complex than you think. SaveChanges is always atomic so if you have just one you don't need a tran for atomicity. But the .NET connection pool has a design flaw that each connection uses an unpredictable isolation level when it starts. It is best practice to use explicit transactions with a specified isolation level always.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a single transaction for all orders (e.g. put transaction outside the loop)?

If you are willing to accept a scenario where some orders are saved and some don't the this is fine, but like #usr said you only need to *SaveChanges* once before you commit the transaction, and you should log the rejected orders.

Multiple *SaveChanges* are necessary if you need to get the identity of a newly created entity for example.

Comment: I tried to put the code inside an using transaction loop but it throws an exception after the first commit. (I think it is because commit nulls the transaction once it is committed).

Comment: If a single transaction works for you, you don't even need to explicitly create the transaction because EF creates an implicit transaction for the context. Your code should then look like this:

using db {
  for {

  }
  db.SaveChanges();
}